# How Change the '23:00:00' time to something like '11:00PM' in sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to do something like calculation for the date.
So basically i want the '23:00:00' to be display something like '11:00PM'

does anyone know on how to do this?I know this might a simple one.

Thanks

Comment: Including the date, or just the time only?  I don't see why you would need to convert the time to a 12-hour format for calculations.  Any calculation would work with 240-hour format as well.  Maybe you can expand on what it is that you are trying to do?

Comment: I just want the time. Yes, but it keep displaying the 23:00:00 instead of 11:00PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this

```
Select convert(varchar,convert(time,GETDATE()),100)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this query in sqlserver

```
Select Right(IsNull(Convert(Varchar,GetDate(),100),''),7)
```